# Non-regular languages fulfilling the Pumping Lemma

Tags: co.combinatorics, lo.logic, automata-theory

Some non-regular languages don't yield to the Pumping Lemma ($L_1=a^nb^mc^m$ should work). But now consider the set of non-regular languages L only over the alphabet {a}. (Like $L_2=a^{n^2}$ or whatnot). The Pumping Lemma applied to some L now can be expressed as a statement about arbitrarily long arithmetic sequences in L. The example thus immediately yields, $L_2$ "grows" too fast. Please give a simple example $L_3$ that does not yield to the Pumping Lemma (and needs Myhill-Nerode or such).
Does already the complement of $L_2$ work?

Comment: I am confused by your question, since in the title, you seem to want non-regular languages that do fulfill the pumping lemma, but in the question itself, you ask for simple examples that do not yield to the pumping lemma, in the language with only one letter. Isn't $L_2$ already an examples of that? Could you clarify the question?

Comment: Or perhaps by "does not yield to the pumping lemma," you mean that the language satisfies the conclusion of the pumping lemma, even though it is not regular---so it does not yield to the process of using the pumping lemma to show non-regularity. If so, I'd suggest expressing this idea more clearly.

Comment: I edited the tags.

Comment: Hauke, for your $L_1$ example, if you intend it to have the pumping property, you should use $a^{n+1}b^mc^m$, since if there are no $a$'s, then you can't pump.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Initial observation.** Let me start by explaining that the answer to your final question is that no, the complement of $L_2$ does not have the pumping property. To see this, suppose
that it had a pumping number $p$, so that any string of length at
least $p$ in the complement of $L_2$ could be pumped. That is, if
$w$ has length at least $p$ and is in the language, then $w=xyz$, where $y$ is nontrivial
with length at most $p$, and $xy^kz$ is also in the language for
any $k$. Since all these words are just powers of the single generator $a$,
we may think just about the exponents. In terms of the exponents,
what the pumping property is saying here is that for any nonsquare
natural number $m\geq p$, we may write $m=x+y+z$, where $1\leq
y\leq p$, such that $x+ky+z$ is not a square for any $k$. 
Since there are only finitely many possible $y$ that arise, let
$q$ be a common multiple of the $y$'s that arise in this way.
Thus, if the complement of $L_2$ had the pumping property, we
would get that any nonsquare number $m\geq p$ would have that
$m+kq$ is also a nonsquare for any $k$.

But this is false, since we can let $m=q^2+1$, which is not a
square, but $m+2q=q^2+1+2q=(q+1)^2$, which is a square. 
So the complement of $L_2$ does not have the pumping property.

**General answer.** The same idea, of finding a uniform pumping string, leads to the following theorem, which seems to be the answer to the general question you are asking. Let us say officially that a language $L$ has the
*pumping property*, if there is a number $p$, such that for any
string $w$ of length at least $p$, we can write $w=xyz$, where $y$
is nontrivial and $xy$ has length at most $p$, such that $w\in L\iff
xy^kz\in L$ for any $k$.

**Theorem.** Suppose that $L$ is a language in an alphabet with a single letter $a$. Then the following are equivalent:

1. $L$ is regular.
2. $L$ has the pumping property.
3. $L$ is eventually periodic. That is, $L=\{a^k\mid k\in A\}$, where $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ is an eventually periodic set of natural numbers.

**Proof.** The implication ($1\to 2$) holds irrespective of the
single-letter assumption.

($2\to 3$) Suppose that $L$ has the pumping property. So there is a pumping
number $p$, such that any sufficiently string $w$ of length at
least $p$ can be expressed $w=xyz$, where $y$ is nontrivial of
length at most $p$, such that $w\in L$ just in case $xy^kz\in L$
for all $k$. Since $y$ must be a power of $a$, and there are only
finitely many possibilities, we may find a common multiple of
these $y$, to find a single uniform nontrivial $y$, such that for
every sufficiently long string $w$, we have $w\in L\iff wy^k\in L$
for all $k$. (I am also using that the language is commutative.)

This implies that the language $L$ is eventually periodic. That
is, the exponents that arise for words in $L$ is an eventually
periodic set of natural numbers.

($3\to 1$) This is easy, since one may design a finite-state automata consisting of a single long chain, looping back on itself once with the right period.
**QED**